# Tradução/atualização de textos em imagens

Tags: suporte, tradução, localização

Vários screenshots estão com as instruções de como funciona a tela/recurso estão em inglês, acredito que isso seja no site todo. Encontrei a maioria dos exemplos nas descrições dos privilégios e na central de ajuda.

**Privilégios:**

- [Acesso às ferramentas do moderador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) << ver essa imagem em especial.
- [Criar publicações wiki](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki)
- [Votar a favor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)
- [Sinalizar publicações](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)
- [Visualizar votos de encerramento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes)
- [Atribuir votos encerrados e reabertos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions)
- [Usuário estabelecido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user)

**Central de ajuda:**

- [Como posso deletar minha conta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account)
- [Como encontrar tópicos nos quais estou interessado?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/interesting-topics)
- [Por que o sistema pede-me para esperar um dia ou mais antes de fazer outra pergunta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/asking-rate-limited)
- [Como faço para adicionar ou remover as credenciais de login da minha conta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/edit-credentials)

Comment: Relacionado (ao primeiro item): http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1231/p%C3%A1gina-de-ajuda-sobre-privil%C3%A9gio-ficou-desatualizada